# Handshake failure in Finished section with java but not with curl

Tags: java, ssl, keystore, handshake

I'm trying to implement mutual authentication client side with java. 
I've generated identity keystore with chain of my client certificate and private key.
I've generated trust keystores with server certificate. 
All handshake sessions seem to be ok, but at Finished section I receive an error. I tried with java 8 and java 11 with the same result, but with curl, instead, all is ok.

```
...
*** Finished
verify_data:  { 228, 83, 92, 58, 53, 18, 245, 6, 218, 90, 45, 85 }
***
update handshake state: finished[20]
upcoming handshake states: server change_cipher_spec[-1]
upcoming handshake states: server finished[20]
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 16
0000: 14 00 00 0C E4 53 5C 3A   35 12 F5 06 DA 5A 2D 55  .....S\:5....Z-U
Padded plaintext before ENCRYPTION:  len = 16
0000: 14 00 00 0C E4 53 5C 3A   35 12 F5 06 DA 5A 2D 55  .....S\:5....Z-U
Thread-1, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 40
[Raw write]: length = 45
0000: 16 03 03 00 28 00 00 00   00 00 00 00 00 BF F7 75  ....(..........u
0010: 39 43 10 6F 28 84 04 A2   E8 25 F4 70 F1 3E 77 7C  9C.o(....%.p.>w.
0020: 73 75 28 75 22 30 BE CA   1A 64 53 1B 12           su(u"0...dS..
[Raw read]: length = 5
0000: 15 03 03 00 02                                     .....
[Raw read]: length = 2
0000: 02 28                                              .(
Thread-1, READ: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
Thread-1, RECV TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure
%% Invalidated:  [Session-1, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256]
Thread-1, called closeSocket()
Thread-1, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
```

Service is on https://vps.integrazioneweb.com:8890/oauth/token

Here's the debug information about ssl.  Could you help me to understand problem ?

[handshake debug info](https://controlc.com/329df7b2)

i used also openssl s_client and also return error:

```
>>> ??? [length 0005]
    14 03 03 00 01
>>> TLS 1.2 ChangeCipherSpec [length 0001]
    01
write to 0x270a6f0 [0x2719770] (6 bytes => 6 (0x6))
0000 - 14 03 03 00 01 01                                 ......
>>> ??? [length 0005]
    16 03 03 00 28
>>> TLS 1.2 Handshake [length 0010], Finished
    14 00 00 0c a4 a4 2c 75 7f ba b7 be 92 74 d3 06
write to 0x270a6f0 [0x2719770] (45 bytes => 45 (0x2D))
0000 - 16 03 03 00 28 66 2e 8c-30 e1 c5 6e fe b4 dc 5b   ....(f..0..n...[
0010 - ca fd 1d 73 ca e2 eb 37-96 fc 89 47 6c 1d 07 aa   ...s...7...Gl...
0020 - 12 62 81 96 5b 7f 8d 8b-4f 1b 7d 97 3c            .b..[...O.}.<
read from 0x270a6f0 [0x270fcd3] (5 bytes => 5 (0x5))
0000 - 15 03 03 00 02                                    .....
<<< ??? [length 0005]
    15 03 03 00 02
read from 0x270a6f0 [0x270fcd8] (2 bytes => 2 (0x2))
0000 - 02 28                                             .(
<<< TLS 1.2 Alert [length 0002], fatal handshake_failure
    02 28
140663681992592:error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure:s3_pkt.c:1493:SSL alert number 40
140663681992592:error:1409E0E5:SSL routines:ssl3_write_bytes:ssl handshake failure:s3_pkt.c:659:
```

but, instead, curl work fine:

```
* SOCKS5 communication to vps.integrazioneweb.com:8890
* SOCKS5 request granted.
* Connected to proxy (xx.xx.xx.xx) port xxxx (#0)
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with vps.integrazioneweb.com port 8890 (step 1/3)
* schannel: checking server certificate revocation
* schannel: sending initial handshake data: sending 188 bytes...
* schannel: sent initial handshake data: sent 188 bytes
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with vps.integrazioneweb.com port 8890 (step 2/3)
* schannel: failed to receive handshake, need more data
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with vps.integrazioneweb.com port 8890 (step 2/3)
* schannel: encrypted data got 1283
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 1283 length 4096
* schannel: a client certificate has been requested
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with vps.integrazioneweb.com port 8890 (step 2/3)
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 1283 length 4096
* schannel: sending next handshake data: sending 325 bytes...
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with vps.integrazioneweb.com port 8890 (step 2/3)
* schannel: encrypted data got 258
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 258 length 4096
* schannel: SSL/TLS handshake complete
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with vps.integrazioneweb.com port 8890 (step 3/3)
* schannel: stored credential handle in session cache
* Server auth using Basic with user 'enrico.musella@st.com'
> POST /oauth/token HTTP/1.1
> Host: vps.integrazioneweb.com:8890
> Authorization: Basic xxxxx
> User-Agent: curl/7.55.1
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 61
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
* upload completely sent off: 61 out of 61 bytes
* schannel: client wants to read 102400 bytes
* schannel: encdata_buffer resized 103424
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 0 length 103424
* schannel: encrypted data got 1528
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 1528 length 103424
* schannel: decrypted data length: 1228
* schannel: decrypted data added: 1228
* schannel: decrypted data cached: offset 1228 length 102400
* schannel: encrypted data length: 271
* schannel: encrypted data cached: offset 271 length 103424
* schannel: decrypted data length: 33
* schannel: decrypted data added: 33
* schannel: decrypted data cached: offset 1261 length 102400
* schannel: encrypted data length: 209
* schannel: encrypted data cached: offset 209 length 103424
* schannel: decrypted data length: 31
* schannel: decrypted data added: 31
* schannel: decrypted data cached: offset 1292 length 102400
* schannel: encrypted data length: 149
* schannel: encrypted data cached: offset 149 length 103424
* schannel: decrypted data length: 51
* schannel: decrypted data added: 51
* schannel: decrypted data cached: offset 1343 length 102400
* schannel: encrypted data length: 69
* schannel: encrypted data cached: offset 69 length 103424
* schannel: decrypted data length: 6
* schannel: decrypted data added: 6
* schannel: decrypted data cached: offset 1349 length 102400
* schannel: encrypted data length: 34
* schannel: encrypted data cached: offset 34 length 103424
* schannel: decrypted data length: 5
* schannel: decrypted data added: 5
* schannel: decrypted data cached: offset 1354 length 102400
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 0 length 103424
* schannel: decrypted data buffer: offset 1354 length 102400
* schannel: schannel_recv cleanup
* schannel: decrypted data returned 1354
* schannel: decrypted data buffer: offset 0 length 102400
< HTTP/1.1 200
< Pragma: no-cache
...
```

Comment: `https://vps.integrazioneweb.com:8080` does not work with Java nor curl for me.Please post the full https url if you were talking about a different service.

Comment: ok, i added url for requests

Comment: Except for the fact that the site uses a self-signed certificate (and the certificate was issued for a different domain `public.rsp.sandbox.com`) the connection works without problems using Java 11 -> HTTP401 received

Comment: yes, also for me, but if i add identity keystore it generate handshake failure in Finished as you can see in linked ssl debug document, if i try with cer, private key and server data with curl it work fine

Comment: @Robert: the cert has CN=public.rsp.sandbox.com but has SAN containing DNS:vps.integrazioneweb.com which takes precedence (although it also has 2 nonsense names and an IP address that appears to be an entirely different machine). Armando: is there anything in the server log(s) at the time of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

i solved problem regenerating my keyset and certificate using other steps, but i also need to know where is the problem in first case.

In first case (with problem) to generate ca files i used:

```
openssl genrsa -out ca.private 3072
openssl req -new -x509 -days 365 -key ca.private -out ca.crt
```

to generate client files i used:

```
openssl genrsa -out client.private 3072
openssl req -new -key client.private -out client.csr
openssl x509 -req -in client.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.private -CAcreateserial -out client.crt
```

Instead in second case (without problem) to generate ca files i used:

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -new -x509 -sha256 -days 365 -out ca.crt -keyout ca.key -nodes
```

to generate client files i used:

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -new -sha256 -out client.csr -keyout client.key -nodes
openssl x509 -req -in client.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -CAcreateserial -out client.crt -days 365 -sha256
```